# Is there a good (visual) Git tool for Mac OS X or Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, git

I'm looking at porting my projects to Git from SVN (I'm convinced that Git is worth the move) and I'm trying to come up with a set of tools to use for the project.  I've googled around for some tools but I wasn't really impressed with what I found.

What visual tools are recommended for Git users on Mac OS X?  What about Windows?  (I have multiple development environments and I need git tooling in each one of them)

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83789/what-is-the-best-git-gui-on-osx

Comment: another great choice as of 2019 is gitkraken

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's one for Mac: [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/)

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Here's one better: GitX(L) http://gitx.laullon.com/. Its the same GitX you know and love, but with more features. I prefer it to the original

Comment: @Carl: Broken link?

Comment: @Mehrdad Its been a long time since I've used a Mac now, but try http://macappstore.org/laullon-gitx/

Answer (score 31):

Windows has [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/). It is not as mature as TortoiseSVN, but I've been using it and it works well enough for my purposes.

Screenshot:
[image]

EDIT [Dec 2014]: I'd also recommend looking at [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17406982/1631). Github's UI is probably the most mature/supported tool out there now (even if you don't use Github!)

Comment: Is the same Software available for Mac OS. Please post the URL if its have.

Comment: used it on win. great tool. still searching for something similar on Mac

Comment: just found GitSnail. TortoiseGit clone. Looks nice at first sight

Comment: Tortoise integrates nicely with Windows Explorer, overlaying file and folder status icons.

Comment: I really really miss it

Answer (score 30):

[Source Tree (for MAC)](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sourcetree/id411678673?mt=12&ls=1)

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Proprietary app from Atlassian. Not such kawai UI as in GitX, but it works. Medium place between GitX and Git Extension IMHO.

Comment: This tool is absolutely confusing when it comes to resolving complex merge issues.

Comment: check also https://git-scm.com/download/gui/mac

Comment: Lacks a lot of functionality :( Like edit file inplace vs TortoiseGit.

Comment: I want to downvote this 10 times.

Answer (score 18):

Try [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/).

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I have not come across a better free Git GUI for Windows.

Answer (score 4):

*In the vein of teaching how to fish*: take a look at https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools page on Git Wiki, which has section about GUIs.

Git Homepage also has section about GUIs: http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Comment: This is a great resource, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/) for Mac OSX.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

GitGui comes with git. It has always worked great for me. Is there some problem you have with it?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: i cant figure out how to Start it in mac os x

Comment: The command is "git gui"

Comment: @carleeto - It is now. Two years ago when I wrote this answer, `git-gui` also worked.

Comment: While trying to execute command "git gui" its showing GUi is not a git Command. Please give me some references for git GUI. Using mac Maverics.

sreekanths-mini:~ Reddy$ git GUI
git: 'GUI' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Comment: @sri_bb - Well, this is a 5 year old answer, so things change. I don't have a Mac either, or know what exactly you installed. Consider posting this as a question. I see there's already [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673257/git-gui-and-gitk-not-present-after-installing-git) for Ubuntu, and for [Mountain Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722830/git-gui-not-working-after-installing-mountain-lion)

Answer (score 1):

For OSX I don't like Tower. I have had too many crashes and problems. On the other hand, Source Tree works very well. Albeit it requires a bit more understanding of git itself. IMO Tower is no Cornerstone. I wish Cornerstone would support GIT.

Answer (score 0):

There is a native port of Git to Windows, called mysysgit.

If you use Eclipse, there's a Git client that hooks into that - egit.
TortoiseGit is a standalone GUI client.
Git#/GitSharp is a client for git for .NET.

Mac users will hopefully be able to provide some examples for MacOS.

Enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

Git extensions for Windows works great and integrates with Visual Studio (if you need it). I haven't tried TortoiseGit, but I've heard it's not quite ready.

On Mac, I've tried GitX and wasn't very impressed. It seems to missing many of the git commands and I have to use the terminal on a regular basis. There is another one called Gity, but it's very new and I have not tried it yet. It is free now, but I think that will end once it reaches 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

For **Windows**, I recommend the **[GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/)** client (which also works with other local and remote repositories, even though it's setup to work with Github by default).

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: It is extra simple. It can only push commit to Git(Hub) but no complex operations support.