# git gui not working after installing in Mac (e.g. Mountain Lion)

Tags: git

When I ran `git gui`, I got this:

```
$ git gui
git: 'gui' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean one of these?
    grep
    init
    pull
    push
```

But I ran other git commands fine, including `gitk`. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: For [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) users: This issue does *not* happen with the `git` installed by MacPorts (i.e., `git gui` works fine with that `git`, which is typically installed by MacPorts at `/opt/local/bin/git`), but this issue *does* happen with `/usr/bin/git`. So if you observe the reported error, then likely `/usr/bin/` appears in your environment's `PATH` *before* `/opt/local/bin` (assuming the latter is in the `PATH`). To find out, run `which -a git`. A convenient place to update the path is the file `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Edit your git config to an add an entry for gui in the alias section

```
nano ~/.gitconfig
```

> [alias]
>
> gui = !sh -c '/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui'

### Edit 2020

It looks like the path in the original answer is now obsolete. Updated instructions:

> [alias]
>
> gui = !sh -c '/usr/local/opt/git/bin/git gui'

Comment: Or, to do this from the command line:
`git config --global --add alias.gui '!sh -c '/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui''`

Comment: $ git gui
sh: /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui: No such file or directory
fatal: While expanding alias 'gui': 'sh -c /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui': No such file or directory

Comment: As of OS X Mavericks and git-1.8.3.4, brew seems to install git to a slightly different path, that includes an `opt` : /usr/local/opt/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui

Comment: @Roberto: I'm on Mavericks and git-1.8.3.4, and there is not `opt` in the path.

Comment: That didn't work very well for me - for example, "git gui blame" wouldn't bring up the blame gui. only the generic git-gui.

Comment: Been having the same error message on Linux Mint 18 on several different workstations.  When starting `git-gui` from a menu in `gitk`, that error message prints to the console.  This was the fix.  Of course, the path to `git-gui` is different on Linux Mint but that path can be determined by running `locate git-core/git-gui`.  Here's my config: `[alias]
    gui = !sh -c '/usr/lib/git-core/git-gui'
`

Comment: for those needing the path, try `which git-gui` - leaving this here as much as a reminder for myself as for others less familiar with terminal (:

Answer (score 31):

This post: http://www.cmsimike.com/blog/2012/07/30/git-gui-and-osx-mountain-lion/ saves me.

Edit `~/.bash_profile` and put in

```
alias gui='/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui'
```

Now the new command is `gui` instead of `git gui`.

**EDIT (28 Jan 2013)**

I have found a better answer to why `git gui` wasn't working: [Did Apple remove the 'git gui' command in XCode 4.5 command line tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667936/did-apple-remove-the-git-gui-command-in-xcode-4-5-command-line-tools). Please refer to this solution instead.

Apple did indeed remove the 'git gui' command.  I decided to just homebrew git instead of relying on the XCode command line tools.

```
brew install git
```

Then I edited the /etc/paths file to have the /usr/local/bin directory come before the /usr/bin directory, because that wasn't right either.  Then exited the terminal window and restarted, and now I get:

```
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git

$ git --version
git version 1.7.12.1
```

and the git gui command works again.

**EDIT (2020-02-03)**

As of version 2.25.0_1, `git gui` is now provided by a separate formula in brew, named `git-gui`. See the following PR and issues for the background to this change: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/49136

So along with installing Homebrew's `git`, to have access to `git gui` one must run

```
brew install git-gui
```

Comment: or edit your git config gui = !sh -c '/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui'

Comment: @Drew I'd like to use the solution you suggested but I can't make it work. Could you explain a little bit more in detail?

Comment: This worked for me on OS X 10.9 Mavericks. Are there any potential side effects from modifying my /etc/paths in this way?

Comment: @Elliot, sorry not sure about that.

Answer (score 16):

Seems like in mid-2021 all answers got obsolete (even mine!), so here's my new answer:

```
brew install git-gui || brew upgrade git-gui
git gui || /usr/local/opt/git/bin/git gui
```

**OLD ANSWER**: Seems like in late 2017 all answers above got obsolete, so here's my new answer:

```
brew install git || brew upgrade git
git gui || /usr/local/opt/git/bin/git gui
```

Comment: like the answers below, `git` and `git-gui` are now separate packages, but `git-gui` will also install `gitk`. I needed to also `ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/git /usr/local/bin/` as my mac was refusing to pick up the new git version (2.33.1 at this time)

Answer (score 13):

2020

```
brew install git
brew install git-gui
git config --global --add alias.gui '!sh -c '/usr/local/opt/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui''
```

Now, enjoy:

```
git gui
```

Comment: Thanks for the 2020 update. I didn't need to add the global alias for it to work as expected. Brew installing both formulas alone did the trick.

Comment: I needed to do only `brew install git-gui` and it started working.

Comment: make sure the path matches the location of `git-gui`. my gitk and git didn't need the alias configuring in git config, though I did symlink homebrew's git to my local bin

Answer (score 3):

You might need to install/upgrade separately the git-gui package after installing Mountain Lion.
As mentioned in "[Git GUI client for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1518844/6309)", `git gui` has its own package (beside `git-core`).

From the comments, it seems a git-gui package isn't yet available for Mountain Lion.
However, [this post](http://www.1771.in/coda-2-mountain-lion-git.html) report making work an *alternative gui* like **[Source Tree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)**.
That could be a good workaround.

[image: Source Tree App]

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to install it as a separate package in Mac.

Comment: thanks. But I have done that, and ML doesn't allow it to install because it's not from a verified developer.

Comment: @Victor and following http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/mountain-lion-git-fix/ , would you see the git gui package?

Comment: That fixed the git command which I did earlier, after that git gui doesn't work still.

Comment: @Victor ok, so it was only about `git-core`, not `git-gui` package.

Comment: My git is working fine. Git status, gitk, etc. all work except git gui.

Comment: @Victor that leaves you with, pendng the publication of the git gui package, with alternative packages for gui like **SourceTree**: http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/ is supposed to work with ML (as mentioned 4 days ago in http://www.1771.in/coda-2-mountain-lion-git.html)

Comment: nice repo you used in your screenshot!

Comment: @knocte Why? It came from an article no longer available. (I now only find https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/mountain-lion-git-fix/)

Comment: cause it's mono :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. Git-gui appears still installed for me (/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui is my location) but it doesn't just work without specifying the full path. This indicates a path issue, but I've not looked into it much further.

**edit**
Try adding /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core to the beginning of your PATH variable. Looks like all the git binaries are there so that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the path worked for me.

I just added this line to my ~/.profile and git gui is alive once again. &(%ing mountain lion.
export PATH=PATH:/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core

Comment: '$' (dollar sign) should be in front of $PATH (like this) on right side of '=' (equals sign)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Victor's answer above, you need to an additional step, because brew install git didn't create simlink for git-gui.

Inside /usr/local/bin, run the following:

ln -s ../Cellar/git/1.8.3.2/libexec/git-core/git-gui git-gui

(Replace git version with your own)

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure how to open git gui from the terminal in Mountain Lion it is possible to use it using OpenInGitGUI which opens git gui from Finder. The download and instructions are available [here](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/wiki/OpenInGitGui).

This may not be quite as convenient as typing 'git gui' in the terminal but it is pretty close. Basically all you need to do is type 'open .' to open the current directory in Finder and then click the Git button to open up git gui.