# Did Apple remove the 'git gui' command in Xcode 4.5 command line tools?

Tags: git, xcode4.5, git-gui

After updating to Xcode 4.5 and installing the developer tools I can no longer run the 'git gui' command from the command line. It says:

```
$ git gui
git: 'gui' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

I'm running this version:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)
```

Searching the git docs (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) shows 'git gui' should be available, and hasn't changed since version 1.7.7.  So did this Apple version of git remove this command?  I use it all the time!

Comment: Maybe you need an `xcode-select`, as described in http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/you-dont-need-the-xcode-command-line-tools/ ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I was a little nervous about running the script to completely remove XCode command line tools.  It would probably work, but I couldn't undo it if something went wrong, so I went with the solution below.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Apple did indeed remove the 'git gui' command, probably because they were [removing X11](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/02/17/apple-removes-x11-in-os-x-mountain-lion-shifts-support-to-open-source-xquartz/) which 'git gui' is based on.

I decided to just homebrew git instead of relying on the Xcode command line tools.

```
brew install git
```

Then I edited the /etc/paths file to have the /usr/local/bin directory come before the /usr/bin directory, because that wasn't right either.  Then exited the terminal window and restarted, and now I get:

```
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git

$ git --version
git version 1.7.12.1
```

and the git gui command works again.

Comment: "Apple did indeed remove the 'git gui' command"? Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

`sudo vi ~/.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
gui = !sh -c '/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui'
```

Answer (score 1):

this is an old question - on newer systems, see [git gui not working after installing in Mac (e.g. Mountain Lion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722830/git-gui-not-working-after-installing-in-mac-e-g-mountain-lion/11794702#11794702)
I'm on Big Sur, but apart from the paths used <s>and symlinking new `git`</s>, the instructions were the same.

I used homebrew to install git & git-gui, <s>then symlinked `git` to my local bin to make sure it used that over the Apple version.</s>

`gitk` is part of the `git-gui` package.

```
brew install git

brew install git-gui
```

close all terminal windows and open a new one
(I used a symlink until I realised I had other terminal windows open that were messing with my `$PATH`)

check version and paths:

```
which git 
which git-gui
git --version
```