# Git GUI and gitk is not present after installing Git

Tags: git, ubuntu-11.10

I am using [Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_11.10_.28Oneiric_Ocelot.29) and have just installed Git using

```
sudo apt-get install
```

The basic Git commands seem to work.  (I have created a repository and added a directory structure to it.) But not Git GUI or gitk.  This is what I get:

```
sudo git gui
```

Output:

```
git: 'gui' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.


Did you mean one of these?
grep
init
pull
push
```

For gitk:

```
sudo gitk
```

Output:

```
sudo: gitk: command not found
```

Do those commands run on Ubuntu and do I need to install them separately?

Comment: why sudo?
gitk needs to be separately installed. Not sure what git-gui is?

Comment: In Ubuntu (and Debian), Git has split gitk and git-gui out of the main `git` (previously `git-core`) package a while ago. They'll need to be installed additionally (or install `git-all` which will have them installed as well)

Comment: I use sudo because the directory is owned by www-data.

Comment: I used git-all.  Probably blew away a lot more disk space that I needed to solve this problem but will make sure I have all the tools for the future and I have over 400 GB.  Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install git-gui gitk
```

Comment: Thanks.  I used git-all which also worked but the way you mention is probably a lot more efficient in terms of disk space usage.  Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo apt-get install git-gui gitk
```

After installing it, it's very probable that no menu item appears in your desktop or `.`. To open them, open Terminal (usually, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and type

```
git gui
```

or

```
gitk
```

Answer (score 2):

When you get an error during installing Git GUI as below,

```
sudo apt-get install git-gui 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package git-gui is not available, but is referred to by another package.
```

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source:

> E: Package 'git-gui' has no installation candidate

Try this command as

1. sudo apt-get install update
2. sudo apt-get install git-gui

Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For a [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) system you can use the following command:

`sudo yum install git-gui gitk`

Answer (score 0):

You can install all Git functions using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core git-gui git-doc
```

Answer (score 0):

To install git-gui, type this command:

```
sudo apt-get install git-gui
```

Then to open git-gui, type:

```
git citool
```